# How can I make text center between two grids?

Tags: photoshop

So I want my text to center between two grids (so it doesn't get past them, it centers there.  Right now it's looking like that. 
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ODAX.png)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

just use the type tool to mark the marque between the guides and you are all set.
choose type tool(aka T on your keyboard) >> click and drag >> type your text
have fun